# Automate changing default gateway

Tags: gateway

I type the "neat" command (CentOS) A network configuration pop-up window is displayed.
I double click on active eth1 
And I change the Default gaeway address

Is there anyway to automate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the two commands below

route del default # This removes the current default gateway
route add default gw "ipaddress" # This adds the new default gateway

This way you do not even have to restart the network.

Comment: these changes will vanish after restart of the system.

Answer (score 1):

the gateway is saved in the file `/etc/sysconfig/network`. in the file you'll find an entry `GATEWAY=a.b.c.d`. you could change this with:

```
sed -i -e 's/ol\.d\.i\.p/ne\.w\.i\.p/' /etc/sysconfig/network
```

Comment: Don't forget to either manually remove/replace the old entry, or do a 'service network restart', or 'reboot', to have the change take effect.  Just changing the config files doesn't translate into an immediate change.